# Leaflet Create Tiles

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tiles

It is possible to draw leaflet tiles in javascript without use a url? 
I get data from API and want draw tiles based on their something like this:

```
var data = [];
var tiles = new L.Tiles(function (x,y) {
 if(data[x][y] == true){
    return 'pathToTile'
 }else {
    return 'pathToTile2'
 }
}).addTo(map)
```

Comment: You'd could create a new layer object that extends `TileLayer` and reimplements the `getTileUrl` method.

Comment: If you want to have complete control of your tiles, you can extend GridLayer : https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html#lgridlayer-and-dom-elements